# SQL: Get the value of friend column based on current user

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table:

```
| friendID | friendA | friendB | relation | 
-------------------------------------------
     1          2         4          1
     2          3         4          1
     3          4         8          2
     4          4         9          1
```

I want to run a query in that I can retrieve a list of friends who are not the current logged in user, for example, if I was logged in as user 4 I'd expect a list of users 2, 3, 8 and 9.

Currently I pull back a list of users in one query that have the ID of 4 in friendA or friendB:

```
SELECT forename, surname
FROM entity
LEFT JOIN friends
ON entity.fb_id = friends.friendA
WHERE friendA = :entity_id
OR    friendB = :entity_id
UNION
SELECT forename, surname
FROM entity
LEFT JOIN friends
ON entity.fb_id = friends.friendB
WHERE friendA = :entity_id
OR    friendB = :entity_id
```

This query will pull back all friends for the user, but because the comparison is done using the logged in users ID I get a recurring list of that user which isn't right.

How can I extract the friends ID from the column and then get their information for each row?

Comment: what does friendid do?

Comment: its just the Auto Incrementing PK for the table, isn't relevant to the query

Comment: You should normalize your data schema, so that current user ID and each friend ID are a separate row. Then you could query for all friend IDs related to main ID and filter on friend id's not appearing on active/logged list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your query to get what you want:

```
SELECT forename, surname
FROM entity LEFT JOIN
     friends
     ON entity.fb_id = friends.friendA
WHERE friendB = :entity_id
UNION
SELECT forename, surname
FROM entity LEFT JOIN
     friends
     ON entity.fb_id = friends.friendB
WHERE friendA = :entity_id;
```

The `WHERE` condition is on the *other* friend column.

Here is another way to write this:

```
SELECT e.forename, e.surname
FROM entity e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Friends f
              WHERE (e.fb_id = f.friendA and f.friendB = :entity_id) OR
                    (e.fb_id = f.friendB and f.friendA = :entity_id)
             );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed - banging my head on the desk as to how I couldn't work this out before.  Thanks Gordon :)

Answer (score 1):

In both parts of your query you are using OR to ask: "give me the user *or* his/her friend". Remove the OR clause so to get only the friend, that's all. However, such query can be written much simpler and more readable:

```
select forename, surname
from entity
where fb_id in
(
  select friendA from friends where friendB = :entity_id
  union all
  select friendB from friends where friendA = :entity_id
);
```